# Group by amount of location

Tags: r

I would like to find out how orders are distributed according to the number of localities. So, how many order numbers are going to one locality, how many two and so on.

Example:

```
Nr <- c("x1", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x4", "x4", "x5", "x5", "x5", 
"x6")
location <- c("a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d")
(test <- data.frame(cbind(Nr, location)))

> test
Nr location
1  x1        a
2  x2        b
3  x2        a
4  x2        b
5  x3        c
6  x4        a
7  x4        a
8  x4        a
9  x5        a
10 x5        b
11 x5        c
12 x6        d
```

Is my dataset.

With:

```
test %>% group_by(Nr, location) %>% summarise(quantity = n()) -> test2
```

I get my table sorted by order number and location including the corresponding quantity:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   Nr [6]
Nr    location quantity
<fct> <fct>     <int>
1 x1    a             1
2 x2    a             1
3 x2    b             2
4 x3    c             1
5 x4    a             3
6 x5    a             1
7 x5    b             1
8 x5    c             1
9 x6    d             1
```

now I want to know how often a order number visits only one location how often two and so on.

The result should be a table like the next one:

```
Table
n_Order     NumberOfObservations
1           6
2           3
3           3
....        ....
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Try `test %>% group_by(Nr) %>% summarise(number = n_distinct(location))`

Comment: do you need `test2 %>% group_by(quantity) %>% summarise(number = n())`

Comment: As a side note, `data.frame(cbind(Nr, location))` is a worse way of writing `data.frame(Nr, location)`. In this case the result is equivalent because everything starts as `character`, but if you had numeric columns the `cbind()` would coerce everything, including the numbers, to `factor` class.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I have tried to show my intention in the following figure: https://ibb.co/mChW41y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to create a column of number of distinct elements of 'location' by 'Nr' and get the `count`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  group_by(Nr) %>% 
  mutate(n_Order = n_distinct(location)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  count(n_Order)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  n_Order     n
#    <int> <int>
#1       1     6
#2       2     3
#3       3     3
```

---

Or in `base R` with `ave`

```
with(test, table(ave(location, Nr, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))))
```

Comment: Almost. There is something wrong with NumberOfObservations (Or am I counting incorrectly?). Result should be  n_Order: 1, 2, 3;  NumberOfObservations 6, 3 ,3

Comment: @fuul  Not clear from the comments.  Do you need to replicate the rows?

Comment: @fuul  Basesd on the example, the count is coming as 7, 2, 3

Comment: Ok here is another figure how it should look like: [link](https://ibb.co/J26LsLv). Green stands for one location, purple for two and yellow for three (different) locations.

Comment: @aktrun Thank you so much for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that will give the same output as  your figure:

```
library(data.table)

test <- as.data.table(test)

> str(test)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  12 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ order   : chr  "x1" "x2" "x2" "x2" ...
 $ location: chr  "a" "b" "a" "b" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

> test[, .(num_locations = length(unique(location)), total_qty = .N), by = .(order)][, .(observations = sum(total_qty)), by = .(num_locations)]
   num_locations observations
1:             1            6
2:             2            3
3:             3            3
```

I first group by `order` and create a new variable `num_locations` for the unique `location` that an order goes to and get the total order qty as `total_qty`. Then all that remains is to sum by `num_locations` to get the desired output.

The above code does it one line by using 'chaining':

`dat[ ... some operations ... ][... other operations ...]`

you can do it in two steps by saving the first chain as `test2`, say.

```
# intermediate data.table test2
> test2 <- test[, .(num_locations = length(unique(location)), total_qty = .N), by = .(order)]

> test2[, .(observations = sum(total_qty)), by = .(num_locations)]
   num_locations observations
1:             1            6
2:             2            3
3:             3            3
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution! I'm a little afraid of the syntax of data.table. But I think I should take a look at this package.

Comment: @fuul it's similar to an SQL query. there's a great introduction here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html 
I find it to be a very fast, useful package that helps me do things with fewer lines of code (generally). Do take a look at it!